# Associate idle keyboard events to widget text tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle

I am trying to create my own python code editor. For that I tried to use the [tkcode](https://pypi.org/project/tkcode/) module. Tkcode partially covers my needs (colors in the text for example), but it does not have the keyboard events that Idle has (automatic indentation when pressing enter, when pressing tab puts 4 spaces, etc). Some of them I can try to recreate, but automatic indentation is difficult. Is there any way to associate the Idle events to my code editor using the idlelib without creating another window (since I am making a notebook)? I went through the source code of Idle and couldn't find the way.

I know that this site is not to ask for recommendations, but if you recommend a better module to create a text widget that allows me to create this editor, it would be great too.

This is the code I have made:

```
from tkcode import CodeEditor
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import re

class CodeEditor(CodeEditor):
    def __init__(Self, *args, **kargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kargs)

        Self.bind("<Return>", Self.enter)

    def get_current_line(Self):
        return Self.get("insert linestart", "insert lineend")

    def enter(Self, event):
        for index, char in enumerate(Self.get_current_line()):
            if(char != " "):
                break
        else:
            index += 1

        Self.insert("insert", "\n")
        Self.insert("insert", " "*index)
        return "break"
        

class FileHandler:
    def __init__(Self, progs_path, filetabs):
        Self.files = {}
        Self.progs_path = progs_path
        Self.filetabs = filetabs
    
    def askopen(Self):
        v = tk.Toplevel()
        v.transient()
        v.resizable(0, 0)

        prog = ttk.Entry(v)
        prog.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        prog.bind("<Return>", lambda Event:(Self.open(prog.get()), v.destroy()))

    def open(Self, prog):
        progfile = str(prog)[0]
        progfile = f"prog{progfile}00A{progfile}99.py"

        if(progfile in Self.files):
            text = Self.files[progfile][prog]
        else:
            functions = {}
            name = None

            with open(f"{Self.progs_path}/{progfile}") as file:
                for line in file:
                    match = re.match("(def|class) prog(\w+)", line)
                    
                    if(match):
                        name = match[2]
                        functions[name] = line

                    if(line.startswith("    ") and name):
                        functions[name] += line

            Self.files[progfile] = functions
            text = functions[prog]

        frame = ttk.Frame(Self.filetabs)

        code_editor = CodeEditor(frame, language="python", highlighter="mariana", font="TkFixedFont", autofocus=True, padx=10, pady=10)
        code_editor.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        code_editor.content = text

        Self.filetabs.add(frame, text="prog"+prog)





v = tk.Tk()
filetabs = ttk.Notebook()

fh = FileHandler(".", filetabs)

menubar = tk.Menu(tearoff=0)

file = tk.Menu(tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=file)
file.add_command(label="Abrir prog", command=fh.askopen)

v["menu"] = menubar

filetabs.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

fh.open("833")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to fix it. I was able to recreate almost all but one of the functions. For the last one, I made an impersonator class for `idlelib.editor.EditorWindow` to be able to do the automatic indentation, in addition to adding two new functions to the `tkcode.CodeEditor`.

However, I find this solution to be very unstable. Any better answer is still appreciated c:

This is the code:

```
from tkcode import CodeEditor
from tkinter import ttk
from idlelib.editor import EditorWindow
import tkinter as tk
import re

class FakeEditorWindow(EditorWindow):
    def __init__(Self, text):
        Self.text = text
        Self.indentwidth = 4
        Self.tabwidth = 4
        Self.prompt_last_line = ''
        Self.num_context_lines = 50, 500, 5000000
        Self.usetabs = False

    def is_char_in_string(Self, text_index):
        return 1
    

class CodeEditor(CodeEditor):
    def __init__(Self, *args, **kargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kargs)

        Self.fake_editor_window = FakeEditorWindow(Self)

        Self.bind("<Tab>", Self.tab)
        Self.bind("<Control-Shift_L>", Self.dedent)
        Self.bind("<BackSpace>", Self.backspace)
        Self.bind("<Home>", Self.inicio)
        Self.bind("<Return>", Self.enter)

    def undo_block_start(Self):
        pass

    def undo_block_stop(Self):
        pass
        
    def get_current_line(Self):
        return Self.get("insert linestart", "insert lineend")

    def selection_get(Self):
        if(Self.tag_ranges("sel")):
            return Self.get("sel.first", "sel.last")
        else:
            return ""

    def get_selection_zone(Self):
        return (map(int, Self.index('sel.first').split(".", 1)),
                map(int, Self.index('sel.last').split(".", 1)))

    def tab(Self, event):
        selection = Self.selection_get()

        if(selection):
            (startline, startcolumn), (endline, endcolumn) = Self.get_selection_zone()

            if(startcolumn == 0):
                for line in range(startline, endline+1):
                    Self.insert(f"{line}.0", " "*4)

                Self.tag_add("sel", f"{startline}.0", "sel.last")
                Self.mark_set("insert", f"{endline+1}.0")
        else:
            Self.insert("insert", " "*4)

        return "break"

    def dedent(Self, event):
        if(Self.tag_ranges("sel")):
            (startline, startcolumn), (endline, endcolumn) = Self.get_selection_zone()

            if(startcolumn == 0):
                for line in range(startline, endline+1):
                    if(Self.get(f"{line}.0", f"{line}.4") == " "*4):
                        Self.delete(f"{line}.0", f"{line}.4")

    def backspace(Self, event):
        if(not Self.tag_ranges("sel") and Self.get("insert linestart", "insert").isspace()):
            cursor_line, cursor_col = map(int, Self.index("insert").split(".", 1))
            Self.delete(f"{cursor_line}.{cursor_col-4}", "insert")
            return "break"

    def inicio(Self, event):
        cursor_line, cursor_column = map(int, Self.index('insert').split(".", 1))

        if(not Self.get("insert linestart", f"{cursor_line}.{cursor_column}").isspace()):
            for i in range(cursor_column, -1, -1):      
                if(Self.get("insert linestart", f"{cursor_line}.{i}").isspace()):
                    Self.mark_set("insert", f"{cursor_line}.{i}")
                    return "break"

    def enter(Self, event):
        return EditorWindow.newline_and_indent_event(Self.fake_editor_window, event)                

class FileHandler:
    def __init__(Self, progs_path, filetabs):
        Self.files = {}
        Self.progs_path = progs_path
        Self.filetabs = filetabs
    
    def askopen(Self):
        v = tk.Toplevel()
        v.transient()
        v.resizable(0, 0)

        prog = ttk.Entry(v)
        prog.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        prog.bind("<Return>", lambda Event:(Self.open(prog.get()), v.destroy()))

    def open(Self, prog):
        progfile = str(prog)[0]
        progfile = f"prog{progfile}00A{progfile}99.py"

        if(progfile in Self.files):
            text = Self.files[progfile][prog]
        else:
            functions = {}
            name = None

            with open(f"{Self.progs_path}/{progfile}") as file:
                for line in file:
                    match = re.match("(def|class) prog(\w+)", line)
                    
                    if(match):
                        name = match[2]
                        functions[name] = line

                    if(line.startswith("    ") and name):
                        functions[name] += line

            Self.files[progfile] = functions
            text = functions[prog]

        frame = ttk.Frame(Self.filetabs)

        code_editor = CodeEditor(frame, language="python", highlighter="mariana", font="TkFixedFont", autofocus=True, padx=10, pady=10)
        code_editor.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        code_editor.content = text

        Self.filetabs.add(frame, text="prog"+prog)





v = tk.Tk()
filetabs = ttk.Notebook()

fh = FileHandler(".", filetabs)

menubar = tk.Menu(tearoff=0)

file = tk.Menu(tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=file)
file.add_command(label="Abrir prog", command=fh.askopen)

v["menu"] = menubar

filetabs.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

fh.open("833")
```